# Homography for (small baseline) Stereo Image Registration

Tags: image-registration, homography

If the distance between two stereo cameras (baseline) is much smaller than the distance to the geometry, is it possible to align the resulting two stereo images using a homography?

Answer (score -1):

For most cases (and I tend to say) yes, but this also depends on the geometry. If there is a perpendicular plane and two cameras observe different sides, the assumption will cease to hold. 
Also, in the cases where objects are far and no crazy things are going on, you could also parameterize the intrinsics using an [affine camera model](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~hspark/CSci5980/Lec2_Supp_AffineCamera.pdf).

Comment: Adding to Tolga's response... it can also help if you slightly downsample the images before correlating them.

Comment: Should't the geometry be unimportant at all (in this special case - baselength much smaller than distance to geometry) because the disparity becomes static and therefore can be compensated by the homography?